# Wikidata dump in another language

Tags: wikidata, python

I am aware that you can download a Wikidata dump file from [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/)

But is it possible to only include results for a specific language?I have in the past worked with a json dump file and used python to parse it as well as [this library](https://pypi.org/project/Wikidata/) to get the labels of properties such as P106 in english ("occupation"). But is this something that can be done for other languages as well?

Comment: Are you only after property labels in the target language, or more general content?

Comment: The properties and their values would be useful for me

Answer (score 1):

The dump files should contain *all* language content - Wikidata does not have different language editions and so there are no language-specific dumps. In general all items and properties exist in all languages - the difference is in the labels which are applied to them. (There are a few plain-text fields which are language specific, but not for things like "occupation")

The python library you mention is not one I'm familiar with, and it's confusing me a bit - WD doesn't give any particular priority or special status to English, but this *only* seems to return English labels/descriptions, which suggests to me that maybe it has hard coded a language selector somewhere. I wonder if you might be able to tinker with the code and just switch eg 'fr' for 'en' somewhere. I couldn't work out where that is set, though.

Alternatively, rather than use this API wrapper to get labels for a given property/item, you could try using and parsing the Wikidata query service results, or the Wikidata MediaWiki API - this will give you much finer control over languages returned etc. The [WD data access page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access) gives an indication of the various endpoints.

It depends a little on what you're trying to do - for "all properties and values on a specific item with labels in a specific language", the MediaWiki API is probably best; for "all values of a single property across all items with labels in a specific language", the query service is best.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use the WikiData package you are using to retrieve the data in French (it's in `Entity.data`):

```
>>> # pip install WikiData
>>> entity = wikidata.client.Client().get('Q1')
>>> entity.label
'universe'
>>> entity.data['descriptions']['fr']
{'language': 'fr',
 'value': 'ensemble de tout ce qui existe : énergie, espace, temps et matière'}
>>> entity.data['labels']['fr']
{'language': 'fr', 'value': 'univers'}
```

All the other multilingual Entity attributes/properties like `claims` and `sitelinks` are also available within the `Entity.data` dict (actually a multidict):

```
>>> list(entity.data.keys())
['pageid',
 'ns',
 'title',
 'lastrevid',
 'modified',
 'type',
 'id',
 'labels',
 'descriptions',
 'aliases',
 'claims',
 'sitelinks']
```